# How can I integrate Highthcarts with TinyMCE 6 Professional Premium?

Tags: syntax-error, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-6

I am trying to integrate Highthcarts with TinyMCE 6 but I can't get it. I'm getting errors all the time.

Can you think of any idea you can give me?

Thanks in advance

I have tried some ways integrating Plugins that I found on the internet but none of them works for me.

In the setup call in the init initialization I always get a "... is not a function".